# Passing 0-n parameters to SQL Stored Procedure executer method

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am creating a method that can be called from anywhere in my application that will take in the named of a stored procedure and a list of parameters to pass to it.

In doing this I ran across the `Parameters.AddWithValue` command, but also ran across a blog posts and some SO posts that say this is bad due to conversion issues. They all recommended to add parameters using

```
Parameters.Add(PARAMETER, SqlDbType.TYPE);
```

but the problem with this is if I have a method like mine how do I properly use the `Parameters.Add` method when I don't know what type the parameters are when they come in? What is a good way to address this, or am I being overly paranoid and just should stick with `Parameters.AddWithValue`?

For reference here is the base method right now that I am attempting to update so it can handle parameters

```
public static DataTable ExecuteDynamicsStoredProc(string procedureName)
{
    var dataTable = new DataTable();

    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DynamicsDB"].ToString()))
    {
        using (var command = new SqlCommand("c2s_ProjectPerformanceReport", connection))
        {
            connection.Open();
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            var dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
            dataAdapter.SelectCommand = command;

            dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);

            return dataTable;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should also pass the parameters to your sp.

Comment: IMO you can't have both a generic method without knowledge of invoked SP and _type safety_ to avoid possible conversions. Of course you may accept an array of 3-tuple like `params Tuple<string, SqlType, object> parameters`. Not the best for the calling point. You may also just add a `Action<SqlCommand>` action you invoke to give caller a chance to add parameters in the way he wants...

Comment: You might pass one single XML parameter including all your values. This can be done typesafe and complex, but needs special effort...

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti So you think the best method it not try and break the code out like this but just code the connection inline every time I need to call a proc?

Comment: You could pass a generic list of SqlParameters as your second argument. Then you could just use a foreach loop on the collection and add them to your command. However, I prefer better separation and would make a adapter for each object which handles the data manipulation portion. Creating this type of generic stored procedure handler is often far more effort than it is worth.

Comment: No, it may be handy to have such a method but it'll go against _type safety_ unless you move some responsibilities to caller. When I have this doubt I usually go with an `Action<T>` (unless you're _tied_ to a specific DB engine, in that case an `IEnumerable<SqlParameter>` or even `params SqlParameter[]` are more than appropriate

Comment: Or discard this approach and use an lightweight ORM (for example Dapper)

Comment: @Steve however it has the same _problem_ of type conversions because it doesn't know the underlying SQL type (AFAIK)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the method accept a `SqlParameter[]` and use `command.Parameters.AddRange()`.

```
public static DataTable ExecuteDynamicsStoredProc(string procedureName, SqlParameter[] args) {
    var dataTable = new DataTable();

    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DynamicsDB"].ToString())) {
        using (var command = new SqlCommand(procedureName, connection)) { //use passed in proc name
            connection.Open();
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.Parameters.AddRange(args); //add all the parameters
            var dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
            dataAdapter.SelectCommand = command;
            dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
            return dataTable;
        }
    }
}

public static void ExecuteProcOne(string name, int age, bool alive) {            
    SqlParameter p1 = new SqlParameter("name", name);
    SqlParameter p2 = new SqlParameter("age", age);
    SqlParameter p3 = new SqlParameter("alive", alive);

    var result = ExecuteDynamicsStoredProc("ExecuteProcOne", new SqlParameter[] { p1, p2, p3 });
}
```

Use methods like `ExecuteProcOne()` to handle the individual procedures with their respective datatypes. You can extract this out further to make a method return the `SqlParameter[]`.

This way you can just call `MyProcName` and you know what parameters you need from intellisense.

Comment: Thanks for catching the proc name. Forgot to revert it back to the variable when I was testing it out. I will dig a bit more into the `SqlParameter` and give this a try to see what happens.